# Migrated User unable to login from admin console UI of wso2.

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I had migrated one user from source wso2 (4.6.0) to target wso2(5.5.0) using insert query in below tables only.
**1**. **UM_USER** **(The Table contains users username, password etc.)**
**2.** **UM_USER_ATRIBUTES** **(The Table contains user attributes like sn, giveName etc.)**
We have using wso2 manage user credential only(user add/delete) that's why we had directly inserted user details
in above tables instead of follows the complete migration step.
we have successfully creating token for migrated user base on password grant_type but unable to login in wso2 admin console using the same credential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create access tokens, the user doesn't need to have login permission. But in order to log in to management console & dashboard, the particular user should have login permission. Please assign login permission to the user and then login to management console.